# Are Battle Master maneuvers usable once per attack, or per attack action?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, class-feature, fighter

It says in the PHB that you can use only one maneuver per attack. If that's per attack, not per attack action, that seems somewhat powerful, since after 5th level you get multiple attacks per attack action, not to mention the multiple attacks from an action surge.

Is this supposed to mean per attack action?

Answer (score 22):

**It means once per attack.**

Whenever the system refers to an *Attack Action* it explicitly does so and you can always tell the difference besides it saying *Attack Action* vs. attack because *Attack Action* is capitalized and attack is left lowercase.

This is no way overpowered as superiority dice are a limited resource. A higher level fighter could use all of them in a round or two, using one for each attack they make (getting multiple through their extra attack feature), but that means for the rest of the fight or the next encounter they will not have superiority dice to use. While they get all of them back with short rest (or a long one) they are considerably less powerful than other classes' resources such as spell slots.

Comment: A [tweet from Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/769694042095357953) supporting this answer: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/09/18/can-a-battle-master-use-a-maneuver-every-attack-role-or-only-once-every-attack-action/